# Vue 2 - Can a Global function access local variables or functions? (Google Identity SSO)

Tags: vuejs2, single-sign-on, google-identity

I am using the new Google Identity SSO and, from other posts, am using globalThis for the callback function so that the data-callback function defined in ... div id="g_id_onload" ... does not create the error ... [GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored

This gives me (only relevant code shown):

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ error: false }),

  methods: {
    login() {
    },
  },
};

globalThis.googlelogin = function(response) {
}
</script>

<template>
<div>

<div id="g_id_onload"
data-client_id="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"         
data-auto_prompt="false"
data-callback="googlelogin"
data-auto_select="true">
</div>

{{ error }}
</div>
</template>
```

However, in certain circumstances, I need to set 'error' to display an onscreen message. Is there anyway of accessing it?

Adding ... this.error = 'xyz' ... inside globalThis.googlelogin doesn't work since, presumably, the 'this' is at the global level as well; and there appears to be no methodology for adding extra variables to those passed to the gogglelogin function.

Presumably I could access 'error' if it was, itself, a global variable - but I am adding to someone else's code and want to minimise the changes (I am relatively new to Vue)

Even better, would be if the googlelogin function could access the local login function (where I could set error locally, and not have to rewrite that code within googlelogin); but again this.login() will not work.

## Update

I may have accidentally found a solution whilst looking searching the internet for articles related to Steven's suggestion - use an EventBus

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const EventBus = new Vue();

export default {
  methods: {
    mycode(response) {
      // Deal with response here
    }
  },

  created() {
    EventBus.$on("callmycode", this.mycode);
  },
};

globalThis.googlelogin = function(response)
{
  EventBus.$emit("callmycode", response);
}
```

Comment: could you assign googleLogin to a local function in a lifecycle hook? e.g.
`created() { globalThis.googleLogin = this.login }` then in `login` you could have access to the vue instance.

Comment: Just tried this, thank you, but no success. I assume this effectively uses this.login as an alias to globalThis.googleLogin? If I don't have a function called globalThis.googleLogin I get the [GSI_LOGGER] error, and if I do then that is called by the Google code instead of login.